# How do I create an html link that has a link name, the same as the URL address?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

Is this the easiest way in an html doc to create a link to a page that has the same name as the url?

So basically it will say:

> Please click the following link:
>   http://test.com.

That is all I want it to say.

The code I wrote for this is as follows:

```
<A href="http://test.com">http://test.com.</A>
```

Or is there a more all inclusive way where you don't have to write the name of the url twice?

Obviously my code doesnt include the initial text, this is just for example purposes.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the HTML

Comment: I am just asking if theres a different way to do that without writing the name of the link twice, jsut for readability purposes.

Comment: There's not a way, and it's `<a>`, not `<A>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to copy the URL from one place to another using JavaScript, you will have to write the URL twice.

I advise agains the JavaScript copying, because its performance and SEO costs are much worse than the cost of typing everything twice.

Comment: do you have any link where it says javascript copying costs performance and SEO

Comment: If a search engine spider doesn't use javascript, your link might look like this: `<a href=""></a>`, which is worthless. Google has gotten smarter about this recently, but I'd better not leave it to chance. Not to mention that they might consider this cloaking, invisible text, or a form of black hat SEO.

Comment: Copying with JavaScript would mean crawling all the links you want to change and editing their attributes or contents. That kind of selection and DOM manipulation always has a performance cost.

Answer (score 1):

What you have got now is the easiest way.

If it's not an option for some reason you can use server side scripting to search the page content for URLs and wrap an `<a>` tag around them.

This will require some very complicated regex. Daring Fireball has a very good blog post instructing you how to do this, and explaining exactly why it's actually impossible for this to be perfectly reliable (which is probably why HTML doesn't allow it):

http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls

I've done this sort of thing before (with emails actually) and it's very difficult and took *years* to get right. If at all possible, you should just do what you're already doing - manually type in the `<a>` tag yourself.

Alternatively, you could use something like smarty (for PHP. I don't know what the ASP equivalent would be) to write something along the lines of the following, to programatically generate the full `<a>` tag:

```
{link url='http://example.com'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't we just sidestep the issue by making our links more semantically-rich?

Instead of:

```
For more information on our delicious pizza, visit <a href="http://www.pizzasrawesome.com">www.pizzasrawesome.com</a>.
```

Use this:

```
Read more about our <a href="http://www.pizzasrawesome.com">delicious pizza</a>.
```